# Apply MACRO only in selected components (swModel.GetComponents)

Tags: vba, solidworks, solidworksapi

I have this code that automatically colors all assembly components with random color. I asked a different question with this code before but this time, I want to ask if anyone could help
To make this code colors only the selected assembly component?
I hope someone can help me with this, I am still learning in API. Please see code below.

```
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Public Sub ColorMacro1()

 Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
 Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
 Dim swElement As Object
 Dim vElementArr As Variant
 Dim vElement As Variant
 Dim vMatProp As Variant

   Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
   Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
   vMatProp = swModel.MaterialPropertyValues

'Get all elements

vElementArr = swModel.GetComponents(False)
For Each vElement In vElementArr
    Set swElement = vElement
    Randomize
    vMatProp(0) = Rnd 'Red
    vMatProp(1) = Rnd 'Green
    vMatProp(2) = Rnd 'Blue
    
    vMatProp(3) = Rnd / 2 + 0.5 'Ambient
    vMatProp(4) = Rnd / 2 + 0.5 'Diffuse
    vMatProp(5) = Rnd 'Specular
    vMatProp(6) = Rnd * 0.9 + 0.1 'Shininess
    swElement.MaterialPropertyValues = vMatProp
    Next

   'Redraw to see new color
   swModel.GraphicsRedraw2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected components with GetSelectedObjectsComponent4 like so:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ColorMacro1()
  Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
  Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
  Dim vMatProp As Variant
  Dim swSelMgr As SldWorks.SelectionMgr
  Dim swComp As SldWorks.Component2
  Dim Count As Integer
  Dim i As Integer

  Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
  Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
  Set swSelMgr = swModel.SelectionManager

  Count = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObjectCount2(0)
  If Count = 0 Then MsgBox "No Components selected": Exit Sub

  vMatProp = swModel.MaterialPropertyValues
  For i = 1 To Count
    Set swComp = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObjectsComponent4(i, 0)

    Randomize
    vMatProp(0) = Rnd 'Red
    vMatProp(1) = Rnd 'Green
    vMatProp(2) = Rnd 'Blue
    
    vMatProp(3) = Rnd / 2 + 0.5 'Ambient
    vMatProp(4) = Rnd / 2 + 0.5 'Diffuse
    vMatProp(5) = Rnd 'Specular
    vMatProp(6) = Rnd * 0.9 + 0.1 'Shininess
    swComp.MaterialPropertyValues = vMatProp
  Next

  swModel.GraphicsRedraw2
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jerome. I have new question posted. can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Where you set the object, try this:

```
Set swElement = Selection
```

Comment: Hi Dharman, 
Thanks a lot for answering. I tried your advice and declared 
`Dim Selection As SldWorks.SelectionMgr`. But `Selection` value is `Nothing` 
Where did I got wrong? Hoping for your answer.

Comment: Hi Fergen, thank you. can you help me with the issue stated above comment?

Comment: Did you select the items before running the macro? they have to be selected beforehand. You can also check this site, they have free macros that may adapt to what you're looking for [link](https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-tools/)

Comment: Yes I did. but it prompt for Object required.